# ios swift MPMediaItemArtwork requestHandler return image from SDWebImage

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage, mpnowplayinginfocenter

How to load image asynchronous from `sdwebimage` to `MPMediaItemArtwork` in `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` ?

```
MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), requestHandler: { (size) -> UIImage in

     let fakeImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
     fakeImageView.sd_setImage(with: thumbURL, completed: { (image, error, cache, url) in

            if (error != nil) {
                return UIImage(named: "no_artwork") // i cannot return this
            } else {
                return image // i cannot return this
            }

     })

     return ... // how access to image from sdwebimage

})
```

i can not return image from inner function. how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Well from the code you provided the closure of the `sd_setImage` method has the void return, you cannot define non-void return value there.

However you could define the `MPMediaItemArtwork` inside of the closure. That's the time an image is available to you.